# Cannot port forward a Huawei router

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I spent weeks trying to solve this. I just can't find that port forwarding page. My router is a Huawei LTE CPE B2268H.

[image]

I searched it in all the settings but it simply isn't there. [portforward.com](http://portforward.com) didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I just can't find that port forwarding page

Click "Network Setting" > "NAT" to open the Port Forwarding screen.

Note:

- If this device has been supplied by your ISP it is possible they have installed a custom firmware that disables port forwarding.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Source [LTE TDD B2268H User Guide](https://www.sasktel.com/attachments/support/Huawei-LTE-B2268H-Modem-User-Guide.pdf), pp67-68

Comment: well, i just don't have networksettings->NAT, NAT is just not there. Maybe they disabled portforwarding. but why?

Comment: @AregHovhannisyan ISP's may disable NAT to prevent people running externally accessible servers from a personal internet connection (in order to sell them a business connection or to charge a fee to enable NAT). If your ISP supplied your router you will have to ask them (only they will know for sure, anyone else is just guessing).

Comment: alright. they told me that they do portforwarding adding some weird static routes. emmm. before they said that my router doesn't support portforwarding. i will have to talk to them